# Twenty Twelve as a starter theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'd like to use Twenty Twelve as a starter theme for a website. My question is: do I have to rename all twentytwelve_* functions found in the theme files or is it enough with changing the Theme Name section on the style.css file? I know that I can use it as a parent theme but I'd like to use it as a starter theme instead.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to rename all the "twentytwelve" names that are inside the functions (unless you want to for your own "theme" purposes).  Renaming the commented sections (for title) and if you want you can even change the name of the folder it is in and it will still work once you activate the theme you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

Can I also offer a suggestion?  Have you tried the Underscores Starter theme?  http://underscores.me/.  It may keep you from having to overwrite a bunch of existing code.